# R: Making a score meter / gradient arc

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, gradient, meter

I am trying to recreate a graph that was made in excel. It is basically a score meter or gradient arc which shows the deprivation decile of a certain area. Therefore, it is a gradient meter from 10 to 1 (Red to Green) with a certain value which indicates the deprivation decile. Something like this image.

[Deprivation in area gradient arc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAiNg.jpg)

I need to create the similar graph in R which would just allow me to change the deprivation decile and the graph would show up. I tried to play with `colorRampPalette` and `plot` but could not find a way to do this. I don't really mind whether the graph is an arc or a flat one.

PS: I tried to find a better way of visually represent this sort of data but could not really find any. If you think of anything that is better suited, feel free to point it out to me.

Thanks

Comment: I guess this is just a number line. Draw a long horizontal line and a small vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exatcly sure if this is what you are looking for, and of course you can modify to suit your purposes but here's a small bit of code to get you started. It builds a horizontal meter which goes from 0 to 100 and all you have to do is select the value `val` (here 60) and the text `sText` (here Harborough 003E).

```
library(ggplot2)
val <- 60 ; sText <- "Harborough 003E"

df <- data.frame(y = seq(0, 100, by = 1), x = 1)
df.labs <- data.frame(y = c(0, 100, val),
                      lab = c("Most Deprived",
                              "Least Deprived",
                              sText))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = y)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = val, colour = "blue", size = 1) + 
  geom_text(data = df.labs, aes(x = 1, y = y, label = lab), hjust = c(0, 1, 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", guide = FALSE) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.1)
```

Of course you can manipulate it asyou see fit, adding tick marks, values, titles or whatever else you need.

The resulting plot is:

[image: A Score Meter]

I hope this helps.